# encrypt an emacs org mode file

Tags: encryption, emacs, org-mode

I would like to do full file encryption of an org mode file. I would like just to have a password to open it - I believe its called symmetric encryption - no keyrings, public keys, etc because I know nothing about that.

So far I have learned that all I have to do is save an org mode file ending in `.gpg` or `.org.gpg`, and when I save, I get:

```
Select recipients for encryption.
If no one is selected, symmetric encryption will be performed.  
- ‘m’ to mark a key on the line
- ‘u’ to unmark a key on the line
[Cancel][OK]
```

I just click `OK` and I am prompted for the password. Wonderful.

When I close Emacs and view the file in another text editor, I can see the file is encrypted. Wonderful.

The problem comes in when I open the encrypted file - Emacs does not prompt me for the password. Emacs does report it decrypted the file and then it opens it.

I would like to be prompted for the password.

I have tried many different commands in both `.emacs` and in the file itself and nothing works. Eg:

```
(setq epa-file-cache-passphrase-for-symmetric-encryption nil)
```

I find that most articles seem to be old or for different versions of `gpg` or different types of encryption and so the commands suggested are not suitable.

What is the minimum amount of commands and what are those commands that I need to use to make sure encryption/decryption functions properly and securely and i will be prompted for the password each time I open the file?

I am using:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.20
libgcrypt 1.8.5
```

Comment: Do you have `gpg-agent` running?

Comment: Hi NickD, I don't have gpg-agent running:
gpg-agent[12288]: no gpg-agent running in this session

Comment: However I found gpg-agent WAS running once I ran emacs and entered a password to open a file

Answer (score 0):

See [this question on the Emacs SE site](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45497/emacs-not-prompting-for-password-when-opening-gpg-file). It's a matter of configuring the `default-cache-ttl` setting in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`. The default is 300 seconds (5 mins), so the password is cached in `gpg-agent` for that long. Setting it to 0 makes sure that it is not cached.

Comment: Hi NickD, thanks once again for once again helping me such much with my questions. 

I dont have the file ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf on my system and I dont have gpg-agent running: 
gpg-agent[12288]: no gpg-agent running in this session

But based on the other question you linked to, I will try setting:
(setq epa-file-cache-passphrase-for-symmetric-encryption nil)
and see if that helps.

Comment: However I found gpg-agent WAS running once I ran emacs and entered a password to open a file.

I also created ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf and put in it:

'default-cache-ttl 0'

But i think I have to reboot for it to take effect - I could not see a way in gpg-agent help to stop and restart the service.